# Remove Compile-Time warnings about unchecked operations

Tags: java, compiler-warnings

The following line causes compile time warnings:

```
ArrayList<Integer> a = (ArrayList) b.clone();
```

creates:

```
Note: MyClass.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

How do I remove the compile-time warnings? -Xlint:none and -nowarn do not seem to help.

**Edit**: I don't really care too much about being typesafe; in the context of the code, I'm sure that the types will work. I just want to suppress the compiler warnings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>(b);
```

Comment: This is in fact a better way, if you only need "a new list which contains the same elements" (and you don't have any subclasses of ArrayList, which would be ignored this way).

Answer (score 9):

You can use `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` before this variable declaration, this should help getting rid of the warning.

Unfortunately there is not really a way to do this cloning in a typesafe way, you have to trust the clone method to really only return integers in the new ArrayList.

If you don't want such compiler warnings in general, you can add `-Xlint:-unchecked` to turn off all warnings about unchecked generic conversions. Then the type safety from generics is quite gone, though.

Comment: +1 for the annotation suggestion.  It's much better to suppress the warning at the point it's given to imply that you are aware of the potential issues.

Comment: `-Xlint:-unchecked` won't make it go completely away, it still prints the note.  In fact it is no different than just not specifying `-Xlint:unchecked` as unchecked is "Give *more* detail for unchecked conversion warnings that are *mandated* by the Java Language Specification." https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html#xlintwarnings I think the annotation is the only way to make it not show anything.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're casting a generic `ArrayList` to a non-generic one. You have to cast it to a generic `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<Integer> a = (ArrayList<Integer>)b.clone();
```

Also, in the future, try compiling with `-Xlint:unchecked`, as the error message says.

Comment: Yeah, I tried -Xlint:unchecked, but I didn't understand how to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: In fact, the problem is not casting a generic ArrayList to a non-generic one, but the other way around: assigning the (casted) non-generic ArrayList to the generic variable.

Comment: That is still an usafe cast, isn't it? (I can't double-check it right now).

Comment: @Puce: Yes, adding the `<Integer>` only changes from one warning (conversion from raw type to generic type) to another (unchecked cast).